# Limits inside the inputs of a function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I know that $g(0) = 1$ and im supposed to find $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} (g(\frac{2}{x}))^{-x}$. Would the limit also apply to $\frac{2}{x}$? Then $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2}{x} = 0$ and $(g(\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2}{x}))^{-x} = (g(0))^{-x} = 1$. If it helps $g$ is differentiable and $g'$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot take the limit for $\frac 2  x$ first. The given limit is in an inderminate form $1^{-\infty}$.

Note that $\frac  {\ln (g(t))} {t} \to  {g'(0)}$ as $ t \to 0+$ by L'Hopital's Rule. Replacing $t$ by $\frac  2 x$ we see that $\frac 1 2 x\ln (g(\frac  2 x)) \to g'(0)$. Hence $-x\ln (g(\frac  2 x)) \to -2g'(0)$ and so $g(\frac  2 x))^{-x} \to e^{-2g'(0))}$.

Comment: how did you end up with the form $\frac{\ln(g(t))}{t}$?

Comment: If you just read my answer backwards you will see how exactIy I thought of $\frac {\ln g(t)} t$.

Comment: @UnKnoWnZ Take logarithm and do a change of variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the limit also applies to $\frac{2}{x}$. The general rule for computing a limit of the form $f(x)^{h(x)}$ is to pass to exponential form :

$$
\left(g\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)\right)^{-x} =\exp\left[ - x \ln \left(g\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)\right) \right].
$$

We know that $g(y) = g(0) + g'(0)y + o(y) = 1 + g'(0)y + o(y)$ as $y$ converges to $0$ so

$$
g\left(\frac{2}{x}\right) = 1 + g'(0)\frac{2}{x} + o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$

as $x$ tends to $+\infty$. Since $\ln (1 + y) = 1 + y + o(y)$ as $y$ converges to $0$ we have

$$
\ln \left(g\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)\right) =g'(0)\frac{2}{x} + o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$

as $x$ tends to $+\infty$ and thus

$$
x\ln \left(g\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)\right) = 2g'(0) + o\left(1\right) \xrightarrow[x \rightarrow +\infty]{} 2g'(0)
$$

so finally

$$
\left(g\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)\right)^{-x} =\exp\left[ - x \ln \left(g\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)\right) \right] \xrightarrow[x \rightarrow +\infty]{} e^{-2g'(0)}.
$$

Comment: is $o(y)$ the zero map?

Comment: Sorry I should have specified that I used the Landau notation for asymptotic behavior. Are you familiar with that?

Comment: nope. im currently studying first year calculus at university so the above explanation is a little complex for me

Comment: Oh alright, sorry about that then! When you learn handling Landau notations you'll see that this is perhaps the most natural and systematic approach to finding such a limit (in my opinion at least)